# PHP Script 404s after completion

Tags: php, forms

So I've asked a few questions about large file upload over PHP/HTML, and this seems to be the closest I've gotten -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Media Upload</title>

<script language="javascript">
  function toggleDiv(divid)
  {
    if(document.getElementById(divid).style.display == 'none')
    {
      document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>

<script>
function validateMediaUpload()
{
    var mediaType = getMediaType();
    var mediaSite = getMediaSite();
    var audioFile = document.forms['mediaUpload']['audioFile'].value;
    var videoFile = document.forms['mediaUpload']['videoFile'].value;

    if( mediaSite == null || mediaSite == "" )
    {
        alert("Please select a Media Site.");
        return false;
    }
    else if( mediaType == null || mediaType == "" )
    {
        alert("Please select a valid Media Type.");
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
            if( mediaType == "audio" )
            {
                if( audioFile == null || audioFile == "" )
                {
                    alert("Please select an audio file.");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    showDiv('uploadDiv');
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if( mediaType == "video" )
            {
                if( videoFile == null || videoFile == "" )
                {
                    alert("Please select a video file.");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    showDiv('uploadDiv');
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if( audioFile == null || audioFile == "" )
                {
                    alert("Please select an audio file.");
                    return false;
                }
                else if( videoFile == null || videoFile == "" )
                {
                    alert("Please select a video file.");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    showDiv('uploadDiv');
                    return true;
                }
            }
    }
}

function getMediaType() {
      var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("mediaType");
      for (var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x ++) {
        if (radioButtons[x].checked) {
          return radioButtons[x].value;
        }
      }
    }

function getMediaSite() {
  var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("mediaSite");
  for (var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x ++) {
    if (radioButtons[x].checked) {
      return radioButtons[x].value;
    }
  }
}
</script>

<script language="javascript">
  function showDiv(divid)
  {
    document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'block';
  }
</script>


<script language="javascript">
  function hideDiv(divid)
  {
    document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'none';
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
// Set the timeout to be longer to allow the file to upload, a value in seconds (3600 = 1 hour)
set_time_limit(0);

// Set these amounts to whatever you need (1M = 1MB)
ini_set("post_max_size", "1000M");
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "1000M");

// Generally speaking, the memory_limit should be higher than your post size.  So make sure that's right too.
ini_set("memory_limit", "1100M");

if( !isset($_GET['action']))
{
    ?>
    <h3>Upload Media</h3>
    <form action="/alpha_admin/tools/mediaUpload/index.php?action=upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="mediaUpload" id="mediaUpload" onsubmit="return validateMediaUpload();">
     <p>
        <label>Media Site<br />
          <input type="radio" name="mediaSite" value="slospan" id="mediaSiteSlospan" />
          SloSpan</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="mediaSite" value="calspan" id="mediaSiteCalspan" />
          CalSpan</label>
        <br />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Media Type<br />
          <input type="radio" name="mediaType" value="audio" id="mediaTypeA" onClick="showDiv('audioDiv'); hideDiv('videoDiv');"/>
          Audio</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="mediaType" value="video" id="mediaTypeV"  onClick="showDiv('videoDiv'); hideDiv('audioDiv');" />
          Video</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="mediaType" value="both" id="mediaTypeB" onClick="showDiv('audioDiv'); showDiv('videoDiv');"/>
          Both</label>
      </p>
      <div id="audioDiv" style="display:none">
        <label for="audioFile">Audio File</label>
        <input type="file" name="audioFile" id="audioFile" />
      </div>
      <br />
      <div id="videoDiv" style="display:none">
        <label for="videoFile">Video File</label>
        <input type="file" name="videoFile" id="videoFile" />
      </div>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Upload"/>
      </p>
    </form>
    <div id="uploadDiv" style="display:none">
        Now uploading...
    </div>
    <?
}
else
{
    if( $_GET['action'] == "upload" )
    {
        if( !isset($_POST['mediaType']))
        {
            echo("You did not specify a type of media to upload. Please go back and specify a Media Type.");
        }
        else
        {
            if( $_POST['mediaType'] == "audio" )
            {
                $AudioSplit = explode("_", $_FILES["audioFile"]["name"]);
                $AudioAgency = $AudioSplit[0];
                $AudioDateSplit = explode(".", $AudioSplit[1]);
                $AudioDate = $AudioDateSplit[0];
                $AudioDir =  $AudioAgency . "\\" . $AudioAgency . "_" . $AudioDate . "\\";
                $AudioPath = $AudioDir . "\\" . $_FILES["audioFile"]["name"];
                $FullAudioDir = "d:\\" . $_POST['mediaSite'] . "-media\\audio_files\\" . $AudioDir;
                $FullAudioPath = $FullAudioDir . $_FILES["audioFile"]["name"];

                if( !file_exists($FullAudioDir))
                    mkdir($FullAudioDir);

                echo("Moving audio...");
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["audioFile"]["tmp_name"], $FullAudioPath );
                echo "<p>Audio uploaded to " . $FullAudioPath .  ".</p>";
            }
            else if( $_POST['mediaType'] == "video" )
            {
                $VideoSplit = explode("_", $_FILES["videoFile"]["name"]);
                $VideoAgency = $VideoSplit[0];
                $VideoDateSplit = explode(".", $VideoSplit[1]);
                $VideoDate = $VideoDateSplit[0];
                $VideoDir =  $VideoAgency . "\\" . $VideoAgency . "_" . $VideoDate . "\\";;
                $VideoPath = $VideoDir . "\\" . $_FILES["videoFile"]["name"];
                $FullVideoDir = "d:\\" . $_POST['mediaSite'] . "-media\\video_files\\" . $VideoDir;
                $FullVideoPath = $FullVideoDir . $_FILES["videoFile"]["name"];

                if( !file_exists($FullVideoDir))
                    mkdir($FullVideoDir);

                echo("Moving video...");
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["videoFile"]["tmp_name"], $FullVideoPath );
                echo "<p>Media uploaded to " . $FullVideoPath .  ". Thank you!</p>";
            }
            else
            {
                $AudioSplit = explode("_", $_FILES["audioFile"]["name"]);
                $AudioAgency = $AudioSplit[0];
                $AudioDateSplit = explode(".", $AudioSplit[1]);
                $AudioDate = $AudioDateSplit[0];
                $AudioDir =  $AudioAgency . "\\" . $AudioAgency . "_" . $AudioDate . "\\";
                $AudioPath = $AudioDir . "\\" . $_FILES["audioFile"]["name"];
                $FullAudioDir = "d:\\" . $_POST['mediaSite'] . "-media\\audio_files\\" . $AudioDir;
                $FullAudioPath = $FullAudioDir . $_FILES["audioFile"]["name"];

                $VideoSplit = explode("_", $_FILES["videoFile"]["name"]);
                $VideoAgency = $VideoSplit[0];
                $VideoDateSplit = explode(".", $VideoSplit[1]);
                $VideoDate = $VideoDateSplit[0];
                $VideoDir =  $VideoAgency . "\\" . $VideoAgency . "_" . $VideoDate . "\\";;
                $VideoPath = $VideoDir . "\\" . $_FILES["videoFile"]["name"];
                $FullVideoDir = "d:\\" . $_POST['mediaSite'] . "-media\\video_files\\" . $VideoDir;
                $FullVideoPath = $FullVideoDir . $_FILES["videoFile"]["name"];

                if( !file_exists($FullAudioDir))
                    mkdir($FullAudioDir);

                if( !file_exists($FullVideoDir))
                    mkdir($FullVideoDir);

                echo("Moving audio...");
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["audioFile"]["tmp_name"], $FullAudioPath );
                echo("Moving video...");
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["videoFile"]["tmp_name"], $FullVideoPath );
                echo "<p>Audio uploaded to " . $FullAudioPath .  ".</p>";
                echo "<p>Video uploaded to " . $FullVideoPath .  ".</p>";
            }
        }
    }
    else if( $_GET['action'] == "progress")
    {
    }
    else
    {
        echo("What'd you do...?");
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

As it stands, this script works great for smaller files, however once I send up something larger ( roughly over a hundred megs ), once the file upload process has completed, the page attempts to recur ( as it's supposed to ), but 404's in the process - a problem that I can't seem to isolate. Any recommendations would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value post_max_size 200M
```

Comment: Upped these values a bit ( will be dealing with larger files than this ) - running a test right now. Will comment if it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: No fix - upload completes and page switches to 404 with this URL:
http://www.mydomain.com/alpha_admin/tools/mediaUpload/?action=upload
which is accurate. Thanks for the attempt.